# Flutter run and build issue

Tags: flutter, dart

The app was working fine but suddenlly its start showing the error when try to run or build

lib/main.dart:1
: Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
../…/lib/fluttertoast.dart:154

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.
  if (context?.mounted != true) {
  ^^^^^^^
  2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/me/Documents/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/me/Documents/flutter/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 1):

I believe there may be other ways to solve it, but I solved it by updating flutter with **flutter upgrade**